# How to pop up camera using picture box when button click?

Tags: c#, camera, directshow

I make a program in C# windows form I have tons of function in my form including two datagrid view that connected to dabase and including a camera that direcly connected to my PC I use AForge dll reference to connect to the camera device I just found the tutorial on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4tAbB258wc) and it works perfecly for me, as I stated earlier I have too many programs in one form including that camera and it went out that the camera was need to be resized to a small resolution, so I decided to make a popup button that must show the wider resolution when I click the button on my form.

this is the code for my camera.

```
    //Camera

    // get the devices name
    private void getCamList()
    {
        try
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException();

            DeviceExist = true;
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(device.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //make dafault to first cam
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            DeviceExist = false;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("No capture device on your system");
        }
    }

    //refresh button
    private void refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getCamList();
    }

    //toggle start and stop button
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (start.Text == "&Start")
        {
            if (DeviceExist)
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                CloseVideoSource();
                videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(160, 120);
                //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
                videoSource.Start();
                lblCam.Text = "Device running...";
                start.Text = "&Stop";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCam.Text = "Error: No Device selected.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                CloseVideoSource();
                lblCam.Text = "Device stopped.";
                start.Text = "&Start";
            }
        }
    }

    //eventhandler if new frame is ready
    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        //do processing here
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }

    //close the device safely
    private void CloseVideoSource()
    {
        if (!(videoSource == null))
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource = null;
            }
    }

    //prevent sudden close while device is running
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseVideoSource();
    }


} }
```

I also posted a picture so that you have further understanding what I am talking.
[image]
as you can see at the lower right corner I have a pop up button there honestly telling you I already tried different methods but nothing works unfotunately I cannot post what I've tried because I created it yesterday and can no longer undo the codes I tried. Any Idea?

Comment: Is there actually a question in this mess of missing punctuation marks?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new Form
- Place a PictureBox on this Form
- Add all methods to initialize and get the current frame to the Form (should be refactored to an own class providing an event like FrameChanged giving you the current image)
- add a method like to the Form

  `public void ShowCamPopup(string deviceName)
  {
    InitializeDevice(string deviceName, int width, int height);
    this.Show();
    this.BringToTop();
  }`

You should the really consider to refactor the communication  with your cam to an own class which reduces duplicate code and allows you to do performance tweaks (which you will need for sure later) at a single position of your solution.

Comment: I thried it yesterday I also found out that I should only run one camera at a time so if I popup another form that showing another camera then this form will just end up not working or functioning so maybe when I click the popup I should also terminate the original camera on my main form before the other one starts?

Comment: In this case i would initialize one camera taking images of a bigger size (so that you can display it on the form). The picturebox on the small form can resize the picture accordingly. In the newFrame event handler set the picture to the popup.